# Forwarding e-mail from delegated Google Mail account to JIRA cloud

Tags: gmail, jira, google-apps, jira-ondemand

I'm trying to set up a delegated institutional Google Mail to forward e-mails to our JIRA Cloud instance's e-mail address so that they can be turned into JIRA issues.  I do not have and cannot get the password for the Google Mail account, and when I try set up the forwarding address in Google, Google sends a confirmation e-mail address to the JIRA e-mail address.

Is there a way to check e-mails sent to `jira@myorganization.atlassian.com` to recover this confirmation code?  If not, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Atlassian does not host mail server. You need to create JIRA email account in your organization mail server (or on any other mail server like gmail) and tune JIRA to connect to the account via IMAP or POP3. Please look here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/Cloud/Creating+Issues+and+Comments+from+Email